# Different CSS files for childpages

Tags: java, css, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

i am working on a spring mvc web application and for the frontend i am using JSP files. To great dynamic pages i am using `<c:import>` width different container/child files and defined some basic css in the top-level container. To create a clean html output i removed the `<html>` and `<head>` tags from my child files, but without a `<head>` tag i am not able to define a different or more refined css file for my child pages.

What is the best way to implement a different css for child pages?

thx

PS: the only way i can imagine is to use javascript and load a css file to the head tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option that doesn't require multiple child css files is to append a class or ID to your `body` tag.

Then, you can override properties like this (stupid example):

```
//default style     
div#container { background: red;}

//child 1
.body_class_1 div#container { background: blue;}

//child 2
.body_class_2 div#container { background: green; }
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your best option is to derive your css from the model returned from your controller by using some simple abstraction.. let's say that you have a page for an order, and order has many order items, and has a few actions to perform for the order.

So you have a view called order.jsp, this view is composed of another 2 sub pages orderitems.jsp and orderactions.jsp, then you could have orderitems.jsp composed of many orderitem.jsp and orderactions.jsp composed of many orderaction.jsp (As an additional consideration, I would recommend you to use tag files instead of child jsp, but this is probably just a matter of style).

The your controller is going to return order.jsp as view and as model is going to return an order, with that information in your main jsp (order.jsp) now you can see what you are about to display and build the css tags accordingly in your head tag.

Hope this helps!